# Java Generics : How to test if a field type is a specification of a generic class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types

I want to test if a field of type `MyType<int>` to be a field of a subtype of `MyType<?>`. 
If the field is of type `MyType<?>`, then I would instantiate it correctly using `getActualTypeArguments` of `ParameterizedType`.

But I can't get to do the test :

```
if( (field.getType instanceof MyType<?>) )
```

... wont compile and get me :

```
Incompatible conditional operand types Class<capture#3-of ?> and myType<?>
```

The `myType` is a generic class that I created.
The field is a field gotten from a class using reflection (instance of `java.lang.reflect.Field`, which expose a getType method).

any one know how to ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: How about now? am not an english person so I'm doing my best to explain

Comment: You need to first tell us what `MyType` is? What `field` is, and where is `getType` thing? What does it give you. There is so much information missing from this question. As it stands, it is unanswerable currently.

Comment: I thought since I tagged my question with the reflection tag you would understand all that)

Comment: For one thing, please don't assume anything about the reader. Now, you said, `field` is a field of the class `MyType`. What is the type of that field (in the class). `Field#getType()` method returns a `Class<?>` which cannot be an instance of `MyType`. That is why I said, pour some more information in the question. Why do you want to do that? Where are you doing that operation?

Comment: I am not testing an instance type ! I am testing the field's type ! I want to know if the field's type is a specific version of the MyType<?> type ... man I'm talking reflection !

Comment: And I didn't say that "field is a field of the class MyType"

Comment: You said `field of type MyType<int>`. Please show us with an example.

Comment: Also primitives cannot be used as generic type arguments.

Comment: Also you cannot use `instanceof` with parameterized types. Because of erasure the generic type does not exist at run time. In any case `MyType<?>` would be equivalent to the raw `MyType` for this test since you don't care about the type argument.

Comment: Also `field.getType` returns a `Class` instance, not an instance of the type of the field.

Comment: Ok changed it to Integer .. still not working. When testing I don't really care about the argument type of `MyType<?>`. let's say MyType is List, then I wan't to know wether the field is a List, and then instanciate it correctly using it's argument type

Comment: You still haven't shown us, in code, an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Field#getType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29) method returns you a [`Class<?>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object, representing the `Class` instance for the type of that field. In this case, you would get a `Class<MyType>`. Certainly that cannot be an instance of `MyType<?>`. That is an instance of `Class`.

If you want to see if the field is of type `MyType<?>` or it's subtype, then you need to get an instance from that `Class` object:

```
if (field.getType().newInstance() instanceof MyType<?>) {
    System.out.println("Field is of type MyType<?>");
}
```

You can also do it using [`Class#isAssignableFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method like this:

```
if (MyType.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()) {
    System.out.println("Field is of type MyType<?>");
}
```

Comment: Seems good, but not very pretty ! I would've hoped avoid creating instances everywhere. Thanks !

Comment: @Hichamov I don't think that is possible. You've to create an instance to check the instance, as you can't use `instanceof` with `Class<MyType>`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I am letting the question unanswerd hoping if someone would give another idea (something outside of the box), but after a while I'll be marking youre suggestion as the unswer